# Oracle SQL%ROWCOUNT statement always return 1

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a simple table `USERS` in Oracle with 2 columns `ID` and `USERNAME`.
`ID` is the primary key and auto incremented using a trigger.

I am inserting or updating records using a procedure like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SaveUser(UID NUMBER, UN VARCHAR2, Row_Count OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    IF(UID > 0) THEN
        UPDATE USERS SET USERNAME = UN WHERE ID = UID;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO USERS(USERNAME) VALUES(UN);
    END IF;

    Row_Count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

I am calling the procedure like this:

```
VARIABLE Row_Count NUMBER;
EXEC SaveUser(50, 'Username_1', Row_Count);
PRINT Row_Count;
```

The issue is I am passing **50** as the first parameter, but in the table there is no row with `ID` **50**. But I am getting **1** as the result. Even if the row is not updated, `SQL%ROWCOUNT` statement returns **1**. Can anyone help me to fix this?

The above code is simplified one and the exact code is here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SaveEmployee(ID NUMBER, User_Name VARCHAR2, Emp_Password VARCHAR2, Emp_Full_Name VARCHAR2, Emp_Date_Of_Birth DATE, Emp_Gender_ID NUMBER, Emp_Work_Type_ID NUMBER, Emp_Salary FLOAT, Emp_Email VARCHAR2, Row_Count OUT NUMBER) IS
    Username_Row_Count NUMBER := 0;
    Email_Row_Count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    IF(ID > 0) THEN
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO Username_Row_Count FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOWER(USERNAME) = LOWER(User_Name) AND EMPLOYEE_ID <> ID;
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO Email_Row_Count FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOWER(EMAIL) = LOWER(Emp_Email) AND EMPLOYEE_ID <> ID;

        IF(Username_Row_Count = 0 AND Email_Row_Count = 0) THEN
            UPDATE EMPLOYEES
            SET USERNAME = LOWER(User_Name), PASSWORD = Emp_Password, FULL_NAME = Emp_Full_Name, DATE_OF_BIRTH = Emp_Date_Of_Birth, GENDER_ID = Emp_Gender_ID, WORK_TYPE_ID = Emp_Work_Type_ID, SALARY = Emp_Salary, EMAIL = LOWER(Emp_Email)
            WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ID;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO Username_Row_Count FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOWER(USERNAME) = LOWER(User_Name);
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO Email_Row_Count FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOWER(EMAIL) = LOWER(Emp_Email);

        IF(Username_Row_Count = 0 AND Email_Row_Count = 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULL_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, GENDER_ID, WORK_TYPE_ID, SALARY, EMAIL, LOGIN_ATTEMPTS)
            VALUES(LOWER(User_Name), Emp_Password, Emp_Full_Name, Emp_Date_Of_Birth, Emp_Gender_ID, Emp_Work_Type_ID, Emp_Salary, LOWER(Emp_Email), 0);
        END IF;
    END IF;

    Row_Count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

Comment: Is it the actual procedure you run, or a simplified one? Are you sure there's no row with ID = 50?

Comment: This is a simplified one. Yes it confirm there is no row with ID = 50

Comment: Show us the real code. The problem is somewhere you have not posted.

Comment: Updated the question with actual code

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce what you are saying:

```
SQL> select * from users;

no rows selected

SQL> declare
  2    uid number := 50;
  3  begin
  4    if uid > 0 then
  5       update users set username = '&&un' where id = uid;
  6    else
  7       insert into users (username) values ('&&un');
  8    end if;
  9    dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
 10  end;
 11  /
Enter value for un: 50
0                              --> this is SQL%ROWCOUNT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Code you posted is invalid (there's no `NUBER` datatype). It would help if you posted something that actually *works*, because - the way you put it - we can't be sure that what you claim to be true really *is* true. Please, copy/paste your own SQL*Plus session (just like I did) so that we'd see what you really have and how Oracle responded.

Comment: Yes, you did. Thank you, but that's not enough. SQL*Plus session, please.

Comment: I have added the exact procedure and updated the question

Comment: SQL%ROWCOUNT you got refers to SELECT as well, so - although you didn't update anything, if the last SELECT you ran returned a row, you'll get "1" as a result. Don't use SQL%ROWCOUNT *anywhere* in the code, but where you actually need it (i.e. to check whether you updated something or not).

Answer (score 0):

Add `SQL%ROWCOUNT` **after** the update to get the update count

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
            SET USERNAME = LOWER(User_Name), PASSWORD = Emp_Password, FULL_NAME = Emp_Full_Name, DATE_OF_BIRTH = Emp_Date_Of_Birth, GENDER_ID = Emp_Gender_ID, WORK_TYPE_ID = Emp_Work_Type_ID, SALARY = Emp_Salary, EMAIL = LOWER(Emp_Email)
            WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ID;
Row_Count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's more clear.

This code:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO Username_Row_Count FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOWER(USERNAME) = LOWER(User_Name) AND EMPLOYEE_ID <> ID;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO Email_Row_Count FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOWER(EMAIL) = LOWER(Emp_Email) AND EMPLOYEE_ID <> ID;
```

must update the values `Username_Row_Count` and `Email_Row_Count`, so that the condition

```
IF(Username_Row_Count = 0 AND Email_Row_Count = 0) THEN
```

is always false. And the update is never executed. As the result, in your `Row_Count` variable you get the result of the last select, which is 1 row.

Comment: So I have to add `SQL%ROWCOUNT` statement immediately after update statement and another one after insert?

Comment: @A.M.Roomi, yes, that would be much better. Update this variable **only** when you actually perfom some manipulations on data.